# What is the JavaScript equivalent of php's FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING?

Tags: javascript

I would like to filter text input from a form using JavaScript. Php's FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING Strips tags, and optionally strips or encode special characters. But I can't use php for what I am doing I need a JavaScript equivalent

Comment: How about telling us what the php command does (for those of us who know JavaScript and could possibly help, but don't know PHP)?

Comment: You seem to assume everybody who knows JS also knows PHP. Please explain what functionality you want and what you have tried instead of requesting the equivalent of some random language.

Comment: I would like to filter text input from a form using JavaScript. Php's FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING Strips tags, and optionally strips or encode special characters. But I can't use php for what I am doing I need a JavaScript equivalent.

Comment: @Dre_Dre, you should edit your question and put this description in there.

Comment: Anything you do in Javascript can be overridden by the user, so it should not be used for secure filtering.

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing built into Javascript that's anything like PHP's filtering function. You have to write it on your own.

Comment: You could make use of a filtering plugin like jqueryvalidation.org.

Answer (score 0):

You can write such function yourself. It's not that difficult. The default settings are shown below. If you want to support flags like PHP's filters do, then you need to add more to this function.

```js
function FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING (string) {
    string = string.replaceAll(/\x00|<[^>]*>?/g, '');
    string = string.replaceAll('\'', '&#39;');
    string = string.replaceAll('"', '&#34;');
    return string;
}

// testing
console.log(FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING('<abc>\'"qwe'));
```

The question is why would you want to do that? PHP is removing this particular filter because of its lack of usefulness. This filter has no practical application. You'd be better off writing a function for an actual requirement rather than trying to replicate this useless filter.